# What are some code coverage tools for Perl?

Tags: perl, code-coverage, cpan

Are there any good (and preferably free) code coverage tools out there for Perl?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, [Devel::Cover](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Cover) is the way to go.

If you develop a module, and use [Module::Build](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module::Build) to manage the installation, you even have a `testcover` target:

```
 perl Build.PL
 ./Build testcover
```

That runs the whole test suite, and makes a combined coverage report in nice HTML, where you can browse through your modules and watch their coverage.

Comment: thanks, I am just a bit puzzled , 3 replies to the same question in one day, two of them almost identical

Answer (score 28):

As usual, CPAN is your friend: Have a look at [Devel::Cover](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Cover)

Comment: Please don't link to a specific version of a module.  Try http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Devel::Cover instead.

Comment: I still think the perldoc link is better in this case, since it shows you the documentation.  But the place to debate the merits of these link methods is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43758/how-to-link-to-cpan-modules-in-answers

Comment: In this particular case, I think linking to the distribution is more appropriate, because there are a huge number of modules within it, as well as a tutorial.

Answer (score 12):

As noted, Devel::Cover is your friend, but you'll want to google for it, too.  It's documentation is a bit sparse and if you change your environment radically, you'll need to reinstall it because it builds Devel::Cover::Inc with a bunch of information pulled from your environment at the time you install it.  This has caused plenty of problems for us at work as we have a shared CPAN environment and if one developer installs Devel::Cover and a different developer tries to run it, strange (and incorrect) results are common.

If you use this module, also check out [Devel::CoverX::Covered](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::CoverX::Covered). This module will capture much of the information which Devel::Cover throws away.  It's very handy.

Answer (score 5):

Moritz discusses how modules built with Module::Build can use Devel::Cover easily.

For modules using ExtUtils::MakeMaker, an extension module exists to invoke the same functionality. Adding the following code before the call to WriteMakefile():

```
eval "use ExtUtils::MakeMaker::Coverage";
if( !$@ ) {
    print "Adding testcover target\n";
}
```

... will allow one to run the command 'make testcover' and have Devel::Cover perform its magic.