# Eclipse plugin for Perl Code coverage

Tags: perl, code-coverage, emma

Searching in Google and stackoverflow provides this as answer for code coverage tool for Perl :

[Code coverage tools for perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230065/what-are-some-code-coverage-tools-for-perl)

It was suggested to use [Devel::Cover](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Devel-Cover)

But are there any eclipse plugin like [Eclipse emma](http://www.eclemma.org/) for Perl?

Answer (score 0):

EPIC is an eclipse perspective for perl.Check this :
[Perlmonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=572235)

Comment: Does EPIC provides code coverage tool? Couldnt find one in EPIC